# Adding camera effects in android and save

Tags: android

I am working on a new android application.In my app i have to add show effects on image preview [like sepia,pinch, mirror, etc] and capture and save image in that particular effect.eg: I f user select pinch effect then he can capture and store the image with pinch effect.
I had read some faq's. But they are telling about some ndk's.But  i don't have any idea about ndk's. Please help me friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set all these kind of effects with camera instance itself. Walk though the below code ...

```
Camera camera = null;
camera = Camera.open();

if (camera != null) {
   try {
     Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

     // Set all kind of stuffs here..
     parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
     parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SEPIA);

     camera.setParameters(parameters);
     camera.setPreviewDisplay(surface_holder);
     camera.startPreview();

   } catch (IOException exception) {
     camera.release();  
     camera = null;  
    }
}
```

Comment: i checked in developer site....there also they didnt mentioned about pinch,mirror effects

Comment: supported color effects are:

Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA
Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_BLACKBOARD
Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO
Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE
Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NONE
Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_POSTERIZE
Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SEPIA
Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SOLARIZE
Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_WHITEBOARD